# Inkscape command line programming

Tags: command-line, layer, inkscape

I'd like to be able to derive new images from a pre-existing image from the command line. To do that, I'd turn on/off specific layers that have portions of the image and then save the resulting image to a file.  However, while I can see a number of commands listed in the help to manipulate layers, I don't see any that would allow one to select a specific one and turn it on/off.

Comment: While not being true at time of posting, there is now this [related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/54615/inkscape-scripting-how-to-show-hide-a-layer-and-export) on a more specific StackExchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written an Inkscape extension for work like this.  It outputs one file for each option layer found.  It will also show various layer combinations as needed.  Scriptable as well.  I call it the **SLiCk Layer Combinator**:

https://github.com/juanitogan/slick

Answer (score 7):

If what you want to do can be achieved by deleting a few unwanted elements by their id (say, `layer17` and `layer4711`), you can do it this way:

```
inkscape image.svg \
  --select=layer17   --verb=EditDelete \
  --select=layer4711 --verb=EditDelete \
  --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose
```

Note that this will overwrite `image.svg` with the result, so if you're scripting this, be sure to work on a copy rather than your originals.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (inkscape 0.91). I am on Windows, could this be the problem?

Comment: It likely needs adapting for windows too; the above format was from a mac or similarly unix style environment (likely made better still with Skela's tips in another answer). If you discover how to adapt it to Windows, do tell – it'll help someone else in your situation.

Comment: note that here you need to use the layer *id* (which you can see under "Edit -> XML Editor ..."), not the layer *name* (which is what you primarily see in the Inkscape GUI)

Answer (score 3):

```
inkscape image.svg --export-id-only --export-id=layer17 --export-png=image.png --export-width=100 --export-height=100
```

On a Mac you might have to do:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape --without-gui --file=image.svg --export-id-only --export-id=layer17 --export-png=image.png --export-width=100 --export-height=100
```

Comment: sadly, this only allows to select a single layer per generated image

Comment: you could easily have it export each layer you want to separate files, and then you use something like imageMagick to combine them